# Use preinstalled fluentd installation in a K8saaS in the IBM-Cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, fluentd

One K8saaS cluster in the IBM-Cloud runs preinstalled fluentd. May I use it on my own, too?

We think about logging strategy, which is independed from the IBM infrastrukture and we want to save the information inside ES. May I reuse the fluentd installation done by IBM for sending my log information or should I install my own fluentd? If so, am I able to install fluentd on the nodes via kubernetes API and without any access to the nodes themselfes?

Answer (score 1):

The fluentd that is installed and managed by IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service will only connect to the IBM cloud logging service.

There is nothing to stop you installing your own Fluentd as well though to send your logs to your own logging service, either running inside your cluster or outside. This is best done via a daemonset so that it can collect logs from every node in the cluster.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

This approach works very well with fluentd against ElasticSearch in IBM Cloud and Kibana in our K8S cluster. 
Thank you!

Best,
Jan